# JSF - Clearing values in managed beans in session scope

Tags: java, jsf

I have got a number of menulinks , each associated with a session bean. Since the beans are in session, the values are being retained when I move between different menu links. For instance assume there are 2 menu links - Customer Profile and Account Details. In Customer Profile , details of customers can be searched by entering first name and Last Name. In Account Details page, details of customer account can be fetched by entering customer account number. In this case when user enters an invalid account number , a validation error will be displayed and customer account number that the user entered will be retained on the screen. When the user navigates to customer profile link and comes back to account details screen, the account number previously entered will be displayed as it is session scope.

What is the best way to handle this ?

1. Can I have some code in `beforePhase` of `PhaseListener` to remove the bean from session when user navigates to a different menu link?
2. Should I have some sort of an initialization block which can be called to clean up the variables in session bean each time the relevant menu link is clicked?

Are there any best practices to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store request or view scoped data in a session scoped bean. Put the bean in the request or view scope instead. The new JSF2 view scope can in JSF1 with RichFaces be achieved by adding a `<a4j:keepAlive>` referencing the request scoped bean to the view.

Comment: Hi BalusC , the whole application has session scoped beans. would it involve lot of effort to use <a4j:keepAlive> to make it view scoped? The application doesn't use much of ajax capabilities currently. Should the application use ajax related tags for getting it converted to view scope?

Comment: Well, I can't help if an application is poorly designed from the beginning on. No, ajax capabilities are not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks BalusC - very valuable tip as always. When should I be using managed beans in session scope. Are there any examples?

Comment: Just when you have session scoped data. E.g. logged-in user, its preferences, the chosen language, etc. In a nutshell: [Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes).

Answer (score 1):

We're using option 2, i.e. when we click the corresponding link the managed bean is "reset".

However, you might want to have look at [Seam Faces](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule) since it introduces some more scopes (e.g. conversation scope) that might provide what you need.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. We are primarily using Rich Faces. Will look into the options provided by Seam Faces.Is it bad practice to go for option 1? Are there any issues with option 1.

Comment: @user1042646 Well, I didn't check that but you might have to go through all the beans in the session which might be overkill. Additionally you might check the context the user is currently browsing in since you don't want the values to be cleared while the user browser account details etc. If there is no browsing inside such a context, you might consider putting those values into a request scoped bean.

Comment: In this case what I am doing is , I have added an attribute "menuLink" to each of the menulinks. In phaseListener , I check for the menuLink attribute and remove the specific bean from session. The value would not be removed when I am in middle of a conversation because the parameter will not be passed. In the case of form reset, where should invoking the form reset method? Should it be inside the phaselistener too?

Comment: @user1042646 We normally call the "reset" method for a specific bean when the corresponding menu link is clicked and the conversation is started. This is done to prepare a new conversion, regardless of whether there already was a previous conversion or not.